# After editing a PDF, Adobe Acrobat Reader DC does not give the Current Folder as a Save As destination

Tags: c#, .net, adobe-reader

Version: **Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, version 20.009**

We have a custom in-house command-line app (C#) that is opening a PDF from a dynamic location on the user's device into Adobe Reader, but after they make changes and try to save it, Adobe shows a "Save As" folder list like below that does not include the actual source folder where the PDF was opened from.

This PDF **must** be saved to overwrite the original. How do we add the source folder to this list, or is there some other option in Adobe Reader to overwrite the original, instead of forcing the user to pick a new destination?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Turning off the "Show online storage when saving files" seems to fix this issue. With this option unchecked, when you save a file, it will default to the current location.

[image]

Of course when you uncheck this option, you will no longer be able to save to the Online storage location (Document Cloud). So some people may have to check and uncheck this box repeatedly while using this app.